# NSMutableArray Values Are Not Being Assigned

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

```
-(NSArray*)createArrayWithObjectsNamed:(NSString*)string{

    if (!_numberArray){
        [self createArrayOfNumbers];
    }

    NSString *object;
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        object = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",string,_numberArray[i]];
        NSLog(@"array %@",object);
        [mutableArray addObject:object];
    }

    NSLog(@"value of mutableArray  %@",mutableArray);

    NSArray *array; //= [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];

    array = [mutableArray copy];

    NSLog(@"array in func %@",array);

    return array;

}
```

Hi, when i run `createArrayWithObjectNamed:string` it should run the for statement ten times and at the end of the statement each time add the new object value, but it doesn't.
when I run `NSlog` on the `mutableArray` it's value is `(NULL)`.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mutableArray` variable is uninitialized. In this case it is `nil`, but it could very well be some arbitrary value, which could cause an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception upon dereferencing.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Will it `dealloc` itself once the method has returned `array`?

Comment: If you are using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), everything will work out okay. Specifically, `alloc` increments the retain count to 1 and then the compiler would insert a `release` message to `mutableArray` just before the method returns.